# How to split multiple file name and get last name in output

Tags: perl, split

I have to split the path names I get from another function. I don't want to use any module. My current code is

```perl
my $val ="@missing";
foreach($val){
    my f= split '/', $val;
    say ($f[1]);
}
```

Output

```
xyz/c.html xyz/i/x.gif
```

I want only the file name like this.

```
c.html
x.gif
```

Comment: `File::Basename` is a core module. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @dgw How can i used that one?

Comment: Why don't you want to use any module? Is it because you can't install any? Because you don't want too many dependencies? Because this is homework and that's a requirement?

Comment: @Dada It;s not a homework. I don't want tot dependent any lib. If I run that programme in another laptop or PC it should be run without any lib.

Comment: Alright, then using core modules is fine (as suggested by dgw and Stefan Becker), since they are shipped with Perl and don't require installing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could substitute everything up to the last slash (`/`). But that approach is non-portable. Perl core comes with [File::Spec](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) which allows you to write portable code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @paths = (
    "xyz/c.html",
    "xyz/i/x.gif",
);

# Non-portable code using regex
foreach my $path (@paths) {
    (my $basename = $path) =~ s,.*/,,;
    print "$path -> $basename\n";
}

# Portable implementation using Perl core modules
use File::Spec;

foreach my $path (@paths) {
    my(undef, undef, $basename) = File::Spec->splitpath($path);
    print "$path -> $basename\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
xyz/c.html -> c.html
xyz/i/x.gif -> x.gif
xyz/c.html -> c.html
xyz/i/x.gif -> x.gif
```